# Autovacuum on toast tables in azure PostgreSQL service

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, azure-postgresql

We deleted the old data around 300GB from a table.i can see the auto vacuum performing on base table but not on toast table.due to this  db size is growing rapidly. I am using the Azure PostgreSQL service.
In the base/parent table dead tuples are zero. Is  it possible to run the vacuum on toast tables?.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Maybe the vacuum on the toast table has started but not yet finished.  Did you check pg_stat_progress_vacuum

Comment: Also, perhaps the data were not stored out of line.